# Grails unique with hasMany

Tags: grails

This question is an extension/combination of the questions I asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18295781/account-for-hasmany-relationships-in-equals-and-hashcode) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18285202/validate-instance-of-domain-class-is-unique).

My end goal is to have domain classes where:

1. The `equals` and `hashCode` methods generated by `@EqualsAndHashCode` take `hasMany` properties into account
2. The `unique` constraint of a property in a domain class takes `hasMany` properties into account
3. An instance of a domain class is considered unique so long as one of its properties makes it different from instances that already exist.

Thanks to @James Kleeh and @dmahapatro I think I'm close, but points 2 and 3 are giving me trouble.

I my first attempt at testing my requirements was the unit test `testFooWithMockedBar` in my `FooTests.groovy` file.  I'm trying to use `Bar.get()` in that test, but it isn't working. I don't think the call to `mockForConstraintsTests` worked either.

I'm pretty sure I corrected this problem in my next test, `testFooWithoutMockedBar`, but I'm not sure the test is doing what I think it is doing as I will explain next.

After passing `testFooWithoutMockedBar` I tried to run the app in development mode to see if it worked as expected.  Unfortunately the `bars` attribute in the line `prop1(unique: ['prop2', 'prop3', 'bars'])` in the file `Foo.groovy` is preventing Grails from creating the `foo` table in the database.  Here is the error I get:

```
| Error 2013-08-20 16:17:52,249 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  - Unsuccessful: create table foo (id bigint not null auto_increment, version bigint not null, prop1 varchar(255) not null, prop2 varchar(255) not null, prop3 varchar(255) not null, primary key (id), unique (foo_bars_id, prop3, prop2, prop1)) ENGINE=InnoDB
| Error 2013-08-20 16:17:52,250 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  - Key column 'foo_bars_id' doesn't exist in table
| Error 2013-08-20 16:17:52,309 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  - Unsuccessful: alter table foo_bar add index FKD76E651A96EEE146 (foo_bars_id), add constraint FKD76E651A96EEE146 foreign key (foo_bars_id) references foo (id)
| Error 2013-08-20 16:17:52,310 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  - Can't create table 'foobar.#sql-474_8c' (errno: 150)
```

I'm not sure if there is a groovy way to fix this or not.  The only way I can think to fix it is with a custom validator in `Foo.groovy`:

```
class Foo {

...

    boolean isUnique
    static transients = ['isUnique']

    static constraints = {
        isUnique(
            validator: { val, obj ->
                def rslt = true
                for(foo in Foo.getAll()) {
                    if (foo == obj) {
                        rslt = false
                        break
                    }
                }
                return rslt
            }
        )
        bars(nullable: false)
    }
```

**Is there a better way to do what I want?**

**Foo.groovy**

```
package foobar

@groovy.transform.EqualsAndHashCode
class Foo {

    String prop1
    String prop2
    String prop3

    Set<Bar> bars
    static hasMany = [bars: Bar]

    static constraints = {
        prop1(unique: ['prop2', 'prop3', 'bars']) // The 'bars' in this line is preventing Grails from creating the foo table in the database.
        bars(nullable: false)
    }
}
```

**Bar.groovy**

```
package foobar

@groovy.transform.EqualsAndHashCode
class Bar {
    String prop1
}
```

**FooTests.groovy**

```
package foobar

import grails.test.mixin.*
import org.junit.*

@TestFor(Foo)
@Mock(Bar)
class FooTests {

    void testFooWithMockedBar() {

        // Create existing instances to validate against
        mockForConstraintsTests(Bar, [
                new Bar(prop1: "a"),
                new Bar(prop1: "b"),
                new Bar(prop1: "c"),
                new Bar(prop1: "d")
            ]
        )
        mockForConstraintsTests(Foo, [
                new Foo(prop1: "a", prop2: "b", prop3: "c", bars: [Bar.get(1), Bar.get(2)])
            ]
        )

        // Validation should fail if all properties are null
        def foo = new Foo()
        assert !foo.validate()
        assert "nullable" == foo.errors["prop1"]
        assert "nullable" == foo.errors["prop2"]
        assert "nullable" == foo.errors["prop3"]
        assert "nullable" == foo.errors["bars"]

        // Test unique constraints
        foo = new Foo(prop1: "a", prop2: "b", prop3: "c", bars: [Bar.get(1), Bar.get(2)])

        assert !foo.validate()
        assert "unique" == foo.errors["prop1"]

        // Validation should pass with all unique, not null properties
        foo = new Foo(prop1: "a", prop2: "b", prop3: "c", bars: [Bar.get(3), Bar.get(4)])
        assert foo.validate()

        // Test equals and hashCode
        assert foo == new Foo(prop1: "a", prop2: "b", prop3: "c", bars: [Bar.get(3), Bar.get(4)])
    }

    void testFooWithoutMockedBar() {

        // Create existing instances to validate against
        def bars1 = [new Bar(prop1: "a"), new Bar(prop1: "b")]
        def bars2 = [new Bar(prop1: "c"), new Bar(prop1: "d")]
        mockForConstraintsTests(Foo, [
                new Foo(prop1: "a", prop2: "b", prop3: "c", bars: bars1)
            ]
        )

        // Validation should fail if all properties are null
        def foo = new Foo()
        assert !foo.validate()
        assert "nullable" == foo.errors["prop1"]
        assert "nullable" == foo.errors["prop2"]
        assert "nullable" == foo.errors["prop3"]
        assert "nullable" == foo.errors["bars"]

        // Test unique constraints
        foo = new Foo(prop1: "a", prop2: "b", prop3: "c", bars: bars1)

        assert !foo.validate()
        assert "unique" == foo.errors["prop1"]

        // Validation should pass
        foo = new Foo(prop1: "a", prop2: "b", prop3: "c", bars: bars2)
        assert foo.validate()

        // Test equals and hashCode
        assert foo != new Foo(prop1: "a", prop2: "b", prop3: "c", bars: bars1)
        assert foo == new Foo(prop1: "a", prop2: "b", prop3: "c", bars: bars2)
    }
}
```

Comment: So this is really odd and I'm having trouble finding the application for it. Perhaps if you discussed the reason why you need this functionality - a better way could be found. I've never heard of anyone wanting to do this.

Comment: @JamesKleeh After our Jenkins server builds some software it spits out an XML file that contains in info specific to the build. The file is nearly 20MB, and there can be around 5 builds a day. The structure of my Grails application mimics the structure of the XML. Most the time the deltas between two of the XML files are small, so I don't want to add 20MB of data to the database every time. So if the XML element I'm parsing (including its children) is identical to one that already exists I want to use the one that exists. If that does not make sense let me know and I'll provide an example.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
@EqualsAndHashCode(includeFields=true)
```

or

```
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper=true)
```

Comment: The @EqualsAndHashCode part is working as expected I think. The problem is coming from including a hasMany relationship in the unique constraint.

Comment: ithink 'includeFields' in annotation will include a 'bars' property in hashCode and equals

Comment: To be very clear I don't have a problem with `@EqualsAndHashCode`. The `equals` and `hashCode` methods generated by the `@EqualsAndHashCode` annotation are working perfectly as is. My problem is the error I get when trying to include `bars` in the multi-column unique constraint `prop1(unique: ['prop2', 'prop3', 'bars'])`. Additionally my classes have no "fields", only "properties", so using `includeFields` will not gain me anything. A "field" in Groovy has an access modifier, a "property" does not, that is the only difference.