# Recommended approach to multi-threading in Grails 3

Tags: grails, grails-3.0

In Grails 2 I used the [Executor plugin](http://www.grails.org/plugin/executor) to perform multi-threading operations in services and it worked very well.  Like most Grails plugins it hasn't been ported over to Grails 3 yet.  The [GPars library](http://www.gpars.org/guide/index.html) is/was another option for multi-threading, but with Codehaus shutdown I am reluctant to use it.

What is the recommended approach to multi-threading in Grails 3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The recommended approach is outlined in Asynchronous Programming section of the [documentation](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/async.html). It makes use of GPars and also has some specific Grails features as well.

Comment: @ubiquibacon Grails Async API (as mentioned by Josua) was introduced in Grails 2.3. You can use that as well instead of Executor plugin if you are working in Grails 2.3 and above.

Comment: I have partially remembered why I used the Executor plugin instead of Grails' built in Async functionality.  I was having trouble with sessions when using Grails Async, but the Executor plugin was less painful.  See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18472013/how-to-create-a-service-with-multiple-threads-which-all-use-the-same-hibernate-s).  Guess I'll take another stab at Grails Async.